# Express the Infinite Series in Matrix

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices

Let$$ M =\begin{pmatrix}
        -5 &3\\
        6 &-2
        \end{pmatrix}$$
Express the infinite series $e^M =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}M^n $ (where $M^0 = I)$ as a $2×2$ matrix with entries involving the constant $e$. (You may assume any general properties of infinite series of matrices that you need.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We calculate the characteristic polynomial of $M$
$$\chi_M(x)=\det(xI_2-M)=(x+5)(x+2)-18=x^2+7x-8=(x-1)(x+8)$$
so $M$ has two distinct eigenvalues so it's diagonalisable and we can find a matrix $P$ such that $M=PDP^{-1}$ where $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,-8)$. Hence we get
$$\exp(M)=P\operatorname{diag}(e,e^{-8})P^{-1}$$

Comment: Can you explain why you get the last equation?

Comment: By induction prove that $M^n=PD^nP^{-1}$ so we get $$\exp(M)=P\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{D^n}{n!}\right)P^{-1}$$